# Suppress the "All warning being treated as errors" warnings

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

I have warnings as errors ([-Wall](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall) [-Wextra](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra) [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror)) enabled on a GCC project, and cc1plus.exe is outputting the message "all warnings being treated as errors" on standard error.  This is causing problems with other tools in our build process.

Is there a way to suppress that output?

Comment: If build is failed anyway, what problems does it cause? You probably can filter it out with grep, but it isn't portable and overcompilcates things.

Comment: @keltar GCC is compiling everything just fine, but because that message is coming out on stderr, other tools in the overall build chain think that GCC failed.  I have other means of filtering that message out, but I would like to just suppress that line. That message seems rather unnecessary...

Comment: It *is* failed if gcc outputed that message. If there are no warnings it wouldn't be there. You specifically asked gcc to fail if there is at least a single warning. This is the only thing `-Werror` does.